How to find the shaded area in this geometry question

I got the answer 1/20*4=1/5 by assuming that each right-angled triangle can be split into five congruent smaller triangles.
I am unsure though. Can you please help.
Thank you.

Why do you think your assumption is valid?

While you may be right (and I suspect you are, as the answer is indeed 1/5), you need to show that the right angle triangles really can be split in the way you described.

Let's let each side of the large outer square have a length of 1.  Since Points P, Q, R, and S are halfway along each side of this square, the short leg of each large right triangle has a length of .5 while the long leg of each large right triangle has a length of 1 (since it's the same as a side of the square).  Therefore each large right triangle has an area of .5(.5)(1) = .25 .  So we need to subtract the area of the 4 large right triangles from the square, then add in the areas of the 4 small right triangles (since they're the overlapping regions of the large right triangles and were subtracted twice, and adding the areas back compensates for that).  The smallest acute angle of each large right triangle is arctan$\bigl(\frac{.5}{1}\bigr) \approx$ 26.565$^\circ$.
Let's label the easternmost point of the gray square Point F and look at $\triangle$ABQ and $\triangle$BFQ.  $m\angle$AQB = 180$^\circ - 90^\circ - 26.565^\circ = 63.435^\circ$.  $m\angle$FBQ = $180^\circ - m\angle$BFQ $-$ $m\angle$FQB = $180^\circ - 90^\circ - 63.435^\circ = 26.565^\circ$.  Therefore the small right triangles are similar to the large right triangles.  Since the hypotenuse of each small right triangle has a length of .5, let the long leg of each small right triangle have a lenght of $x$.
$\cos(26.565) = \frac{x}{.5} \rightarrow x = .5\cos(26.565) \approx .4472$
Now let the short leg of each small right triangle have a length of $y$.
$\sin(26.565) = \frac{y}{.5} \rightarrow y = .5\sin(26.565) \approx .2236$.
Therefore the area of each small right triangle is .5(.2236)(.4472) = .05.
So the area of the gray square is the area of the large outer square minus the area of the 4 large right triangles plus the area of the 4 small right triangles which is $1 - 4(.25) + 4(.05) = 1 - 1 + .2 = .2$ .  Note that the four small right triangles can be rearranged to fit into the gray square!  So you are correct that the area of the gray square is 20% of the area of the large square, which means 20% of the large square's area has been shaded.
